# Laravel "with" is not populate related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables in Laravel Eloquent:

```
UserCategory:
id | user | category
```

and

```
Category:
id | name
```

UserCategories relates to Category trough **belongsTo**:

```
class UserCategory extends Model
{
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category');
   }
}
```

But when I try to get UserCategories with Categories I got integer value (instead of Category model)

```
$categories = [];
$userCategory = UserCategory::where('user', $user->id)->with('category')->get();

foreach($userCategory as $item) {
   $categories[] = $item->category->name;
}
```

When I try to get the category's name I see the second error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Curious thing, that when I use `dd($item)` I see that *$item* has correct relation to Category object, but  `dd($item->category)` returns integer value (category id) instead of category model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have conflicting names. You have both a `category` column, and a `category` relationship. By saying `$item->category` its showing you the `category` column value. Try changing the relationship name to something else and see if that works.

The best practice would be to use a column name of `category_id`, but if changing the column name isn't feasible in your situation then the relationship name will work just as well.

Comment: You can also use `$item->getRelation('category')->name` if it's not possible to rename the column or the relationship.

Comment: Thank you! Good advice!

Answer (score 1):

Change your relation name or id name here because here your relation name & column name is same

```
class UserCategory extends Model
{
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category');
   }
}
```